# Annotating line chart with data values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have plot with multiple line charts. I would like to plot data values for each point in each line that corresponds to its value in my pandas dataframe. I am however having difficulties annotating these data points.

This is a sample of the code I have written to try and solve this issue:

```
ax= weekdays.plot(marker='o',label='Conversion rates between signup states')
ax.set_xticklabels(['original','sunday','monday',
                 'tuesday','wednesday','thursday',
                 'friday','saturday'])
for i in weekdays.values:
    ax.text(str(i),xy=i)
```

Here is a sample of my data (from weekdays dataframe). I returned it as a dictionary for ease of reading:

```
{'filter': {0: 'original',
  1: 'sunday',
  2: 'monday',
  3: 'tuesday',
  4: 'wednesday',
  5: 'thursday',
  6: 'friday',
  7: 'saturday'},
 'session_to_leads': {0: 16.28,
  1: 13.88,
  2: 13.63,
  3: 15.110000000000001,
  4: 13.469999999999999,
  5: 13.54,
  6: 12.58,
  7: 12.82},
 'leads_to_opps': {0: 9.47,
  1: 6.279999999999999,
  2: 7.62,
  3: 8.6,
  4: 7.5600000000000005,
  5: 7.9,
  6: 7.08,
  7: 5.7299999999999995},
 'opps_to_complete': {0: 1.92,
  1: 0.86,
  2: 1.3599999999999999,
  3: 1.69,
  4: 1.3599999999999999,
  5: 1.48,
  6: 1.51,
  7: 0.88}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in a different way with plotly. You can first generate a new data frame with 3 columns with the following code,

```
values = weekdays.T.values[1:].ravel()
idx = weekdays.T.values[0].ravel().tolist() * 3 

cols = weekdays.columns[1:]
cols_ = []
for col in cols:
    cols_.append([col]*8)
cols_ = np.array(cols_).ravel()

weekdays_ = pd.DataFrame({'days': idx, 'values': values, 'cols': cols_})
```

, the output is like below:

```
         days values              cols
0    original  16.28  session_to_leads
1      sunday  13.88  session_to_leads
2      monday  13.63  session_to_leads
3     tuesday  15.11  session_to_leads
4   wednesday  13.47  session_to_leads
5    thursday  13.54  session_to_leads
6      friday  12.58  session_to_leads
7    saturday  12.82  session_to_leads
8    original   9.47     leads_to_opps
```

Now, you use the following to get a plot

```
import plotly_express as px # or import plotly.express as px

px.line(weekdays_, x='days', y='values', color='cols')
```

which produces the following interactive plot.

[image: interactive plotly chart]

Comment: This is great, but getting this error message when I try and encase this in a function -> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: can you provide a traceback ? or can you tell which line throws an error ?